Is $r$ when $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}$ "equivalent" to $\frac{1}{n}$ when $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$?
The question I am trying to do is:
Let $f:U\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
Show that for every $x\in U$ we have: $$f(x)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{vol.(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy$$


I showed that the following is true: $$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{vol.(B(x,\frac{1}{n}))}\int_{B(x,\frac{1}{n})} f(y)dy$$
The way I did it was that given $n$, there is a point $a_n\in B(x,\frac{1}{n})$ such that the RHS$=f(a_n)$. So, we have a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=n_1}^\infty$ that converges to $x$ ($n_1$ is the smallest natural such that $B(x,\frac{1}{n_1})\subset U$). Then, the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_{n=n_1}^\infty$ converges to $f(x)$


My question is: are these equivalent? I can think of cases where you can't change the $r$ for $\frac{1}{n}$, for instance, some function $g:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $g(\frac{1}{n})=0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ but it keeps oscilating while in between these values in a way that $lim_{r\rightarrow0}g(r)$ does not exist. However, I feel like I can do it in this question, because of the way I chose $a_n$, but I am not totally sure

Can you show that the limit exists by some other means, for example, the stuff in the scope of $\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0^+}$ is monotone in $r$ (increasing or decreasing) and bounded? (Off-hand, I don't know if monotonicity holds. My guess is that it does not hold.) Or maybe you can show that for $r$ between $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ these values (the stuff in the scope of $\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0^+})$ "don't vary too much" from the values for $r = \frac{1}{n}$ and $r=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and use a limit squeeze result. Useful google phrase for the result: Lebesgue point.

Something I forgot to mention is that in the original question (the one with $r$), I managed to show that given $\varepsilon>0$ we have $\delta>0$ such that there is $a\in B(x,\delta)$ such that $f(x)-\varepsilon<f(a)<f(x)+\varepsilon$. So I believe this shows that it doen't vary too much? The problem I had with this is that I had to show that given $\delta$ is small enough, we can make $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small. It seem obvious to me, but I couldn't find a way to "formalize" it, so I opted to go the $n\rightarrow\infty$ way.

I fail to see why you can't just replace $\frac 1n$ with $r$ in your limit. For each ball of radius $r$ we get a point $a(r)$ by the exact same argument, which still gives $\lim_{r\to 0} a(r) = x$, and $\lim_{r\to 0} f(a(r)) = f(x)$.
